# ".walkfree" folder automatically created in SD card, and APKs downloaded into it without any notification

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, file-system

In my SD card a folder is created on its own named `.walkfree` by an unknown source, and in that it automatically downloads `.apk` files showing no notification of being downloaded, and if deleted, a new same folder appears and again apps are downloaded, and it does not stop.

What is going on?

Comment: Do you have an app/game called "This Crazy walk"? Research suggests that this app made it to store ad data.

Comment: Big chance it's caused by a trojan. Read [MalwareBytes forum](https://forums.malwarebytes.org/index.php?/topic/171034-suspicious-686944448apk-from-mobogenie-allegedly-pou-app/) for more info. Meanwhile, check your installed apps (usually on Settings - Apps - Downloaded/All tabs) and see if there's a suspicious app that you didn't install. **Edit:** for technical-savvy person, check apps that has `com.walkfree.internal.PushReceiver` component.